# Why does my global object instance keep resetting?

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to create in Xamarin.forms a singleton or global object which contains all global services I need in most of the viewmodels. Currently it contains two services for authentication and Azure cloud access:

```
public class ServiceCollection
{
    public IAuthenticate authentication { get; set; }
    public ICloudServices cloudServices { get; set; }

    public ServiceCollection()
    {
        authentication = new AuthenticationProvider();
        cloudServices = new AzureCloudServices();
    }
}
```

I create the instance of this class in App.xaml.cs:

public static ServiceCollection GlobalServices { get; set; }

I have a login view on which I take these services and perform authentication:

```
    public Task AuthExecute { get; private set; }

    public LoginPageViewModel(  
            INavigationService navigationService, 
            IPageDialogService dialogService, 
            IEventAggregator ea) 
        :base(navigationService)

    {

        _authenticate = App.GlobalServices.authentication;
        _cloudService = App.GlobalServices.cloudServices;
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _dialogService = dialogService;
        _eventAggregator = ea;

        AuthExecute = Authenticate();
    }
```

But after I perform a navigation to another view via prism:

await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("CustomNavigationPage/MainPage");

The data within the ServiceCollection is reset to Null.

I have tried to register in prism container (DryIoc I think) 
            containerRegistry.Register();
            containerRegistry.Register();

Same behaviour can be observed across viewmodels, the data within these objects are lost.

Somebody seen similar behaviour? 
Thanks!

Comment: I tried with a trivial object with an int member, and the value within the object is kept across view transitions, the problem is only when I am using complex objects.
I did not add details related to authentication since while in login viewmodel the mechanism works as expected and the object is loaded with user info (token, etc.) after transitioning the another view all the members aquired on previous view within authenticaton and cloudServices are reset to null (token and user info lost). I have set a breakpoint on a property, the data is not modified by other instances or threads.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Let me tell you a story about DryIoc and static members within objects:
The rootcause of the problem was that DryIoc does not reuse the same instance of the registered service, if you want to have your registered services reused refer to the user manual "Registering as Singleton". I just registered the service with RegisterSingleton (Prism Ioc) and received the objects in viewmodel constructors as described in prism xamarin manual. Still this does not explain why I was losing data within my objects while having a transition to the new screen. After carefull looking the global object had the same type as the service registered in Ioc and furthermore had a lot of static members. So in conclusion when a transition happened to a new view the Ioc container created a new instance of the class calling the constructor which reset the members within the class and since these members were static I lost the data in other instances of the class.

Lessons learnt: Be carefull with static members!